# Class Diagram Clarification

Tags: uml, class-diagram, staruml

I am clarification trying to draw up my class diagram for an app that I am looking to produce. I have been following some different tutorials and explanations of class diagrams but I am unsure if I am filling it in right.

What I have done so far is the actual classes and the classes for each of the database adapters. Within the adapters I feel like I am repeating myself and wondering if I need to repeat in every class or should I just have them in one and leave the rest?

I know I havnt added in any relations or parameters, I want to make sure what I have is right before moving forward.

[image: The Class Diagram]

Comment: What do you think is repeated? From the classes alone nobody can judge whether your design is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One point where you are repeating yourself is in the Adaptor classes. All of these classes have databaseTableName, dbHelper, mDB, and mCTX, open() and close(). All these should be pulled up into something that is called ***AbstractAdapter***. All the adaptors should extend from this (I am not sure what DB_Adaptor is... perhaps that is the super class you are intending?).

Secondly, there is too little information to proceed much further. Having quickly scanned over your diagram I can't find any composition relationships and some entities appear to be missing. Eg. What is ***SimpleCursorAdaptor***?

Thirdly, you are missing the domain objects. A Recipe_Adaptor should have a reference to something like a Recipe, an Ingredient_Adaptor should have a reference to an Ingredient, etc. You really need to think about **domain objects** before you proceed much further.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I had a feeling that I was repeating myself with databaseTableName, dbHelper, mDB, and mCTX, open() and close(). I get what you are saying about the AbstractAdapter and thats what I was going for with the DB_Adapter. I will look into doain objectives now. Thanks!